# is there any way to change placement of tabs in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I don't like Chrome's placement of tabs.

Is there any way (maybe through a plugin) to change Chrome's tabs placement, so that it's like Firefox or Safari?

Comment: Where do you want them to appear?

Comment: @ChrisF He probably means to tabs on top, taking up half the window title bar.

Comment: Like in FF or Safari.

Comment: @ChrisF Try Ctrl+Alt+DownArrowKey.

Comment: You'll get used to it. In fact, Microsoft's IE9 is adopting a "similar" design (IIRC). I like it this way better, though. It's more intuitive to drag them out of the window (you drag the blue bar for moving the window, the tabs to move *out* of the window). IMO, Chrome's design is much more appropriate than placing the two "moving thingies" in two different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It does not seem to be possible](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=13ac86f8858306f8&hl=en) (most recent post just a few weeks old). Also, [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4b2d038396d136a6&hl=en).

Comment: its 12years later, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

DataGreed: On my Windows box, I just click and hold a tab and drag it to a new spot along the horizontal tab-bar.  Are you suggesting that tabs should be placed elsewhere than that bar?

Comment: He probably means to tabs on top, taking up half the window title bar.

Comment: i actually want to place them like in FF or Safari.